# CSS Fixed video background div with fixed footer

Tags: css, html, video, css-position

I am trying to put a video as a background for some site (this could be any other complex div content used as a background). The problem there is that it should be a 'position: fixed' one, as well as the footer (this is the requirement - footer should not move with a scroll). I am struggling for hours already yet can not make it all happen - when the main content is bigger than the window size, scrolling reveals problems as in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/h4ss1hLu/

code there is as follows:
css:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#main {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;   
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba( 245, 245, 245, 0.75);
}
#wrappedContent {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#videoBG {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 100%
}

footer {
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="videoBG"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="wrappedContent">
        some big block of content<br>
        it should have the videoBG layer<br>
        under it and fixed - scrolling should not affect the videoBG <br>
        position and its height should be <br>
        equal to the window-height without the footer<br>
        but as you can see - it is not - the red BG is far longer than it should<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
        some big block of content<br>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    footer content
</footer>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an image in your video container for this example but this can easily be changed to whatever content you need. It's also responsive.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h4ss1hLu/

If you are using a video, you will want to probably use a full screen video js plugin for it to be cross browser compatible easily.

**The HTML**

```
<div id="videoBG"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="wrappedContent">
        some big block of content<br>
...the rest of your html
```

**The CSS**

```
* { margin:0; padding:0}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#main {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;   
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba( 245, 245, 245, 0.75);
}
#wrappedContent {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#videoBG {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#videoBG img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The actual problem in the actual page (here I posted a simplified version) was about wrong size parameters of the embedded video + some way too complicated games with the z-index.

Comment: Z-index can be very powerful and is easy to use. Just remember that elements using z-index must always include positioning (ie. position: relative) and stack from lowest to highest.